# F# For loop negative count down - Type int does not support the operator ..-

Tags: f#

Am trying to count down from 6 to 1 in a non-recursive factorial function and getting a compiler error:

```
let fact x =
    let mutable product = 1
    for i in x..-1..1 do
        product <- product * i
    product

// Error on the 6 - type 'int' does not support the operator '..-'
let answer = fact 6
printfn "%i" answer
```

I got this idea from near the bottom [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233227.aspx)

Have changed the function to just count up and it works, but I'm interested to know why this failed.  Is there a better way to count down?

Using VS2012 update 3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Have changed the function to just count up and it works, but I'm interested to know why this failed.

Your example fails because `..` and `-` are two different operators, the compiler needs separation between those. Instead of wrapping `-1` by parentheses, you could add spaces:

```
let fact x =
    let mutable product = 1
    for i in x .. -1 .. 1 do
        product <- product * i
    product
```

> Is there a better way to count down?

The less well-known `for .. downto .. do` construct is more appropriate to use here.

```
let fact x =
    let mutable product = 1
    for i = x downto 1 do
        product <- product * i
    product
```

Answer (score 9):

This works:

```
let fact x =
  let mutable product = 1
  for i in x..(-1)..1 do
    product <- product * i
  product
```

As does this (as used in the link in the question):

```
let fact x =
  let mutable product = 1
  for i in x .. -1 .. 1 do
    product <- product * i
  product
```

PS: also note that there are more functional ways to compute a factorial (bad to use mutable variables); the most obvious using recursion:

```
let rec fact x =
  if x > 2
  then x * (fact (x - 1))
  else x
```

or a one-liner using lists:

```
let fact x = [2..x] |> List.reduce (*)
```

Comment: Many thanks - especially for the more functional recursive ways.  I gave points to pad for his downto interesting approach. If I could give you points too I would (and everyone else who answered)!

Answer (score 4):

Try to use brackets:

```
...
for i in x..(-1)..1 do
...
```